# why salesforce have restriction to add products from one pricebook for an opportunity? what happen if with multiple price books?

Tags: opportunity, pricebook

we have a integration where we need to integrate SAP with SFDC. Now the pain comes to add products from multiple pricebook for an opportunity. what would happen if we add products from multiple pricebook for an opportunity? Is that not logical to business if we have multiple pricebook to use for an opportunity? why salesforce have this restriction? my apologies for more questions here Expert answers is helpful to understand this issue better...

Thanks
Baskaran

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a pure business logic.

There are different pricebooks for same products. This is because you may have different type of customers for the same product.

One customer who purchase in bulk, for him you will have pricebook with some discount. Other customers who don't purchase in bulk you will have pricebook without discounts. There can be other scenarios that you have few loyal customers for whom you have completely different pricebook. So, keep these pricebooks private for individual customers (opportunity) Salesforce   make them completely isolated and didn't provide any gap that these pricebook can be shared.

In an organisation there can be two different opportunities which have different deal for same product and for good relationship there price book must not be shared with each other anyhow otherwise this will have negative impact on trust and goodwill.